# Delphi TClientSocket replacement using winsock2 and IOCP?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, winsock2, iocp

Is there such a thing? It needs to be asynchronous (no Indy).

Comment: May I ask why you need it to be that way?

Comment: Under heavy load Windows Messages have been flakey so IOCP. Secondly Winsock2 gives us easy SSL.

Answer (score 2):

Try HPScktSrvr - http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=220#939383

Comment: This also isn't suitabled for Delphi 2009.

Comment: And I just realised the distribution .zip is missing files as well.

Comment: I use it with Delphi 2009, for me it works without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

These may or may not be what you are looking for, but worth a shot:

- [Ararat Synapse](http://www.synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php) - For Delphi 2009 support you need to get the latest from SVN.
- [/n Software's IP*Works](http://www.nsoftware.com/portal/borland/) - Commercial, but very full featured.

Good luck!

Comment: Neither appear to be IOCP. Do you have links to information that confirms they are both IOCP and Winsock2?

Comment: Nope, but there were the closest I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://voipobjects.com/index.php?page=delphi-iocp-library 
It is migrated iocpclasses.sourceforge.net (i'm an author). Enjoy :)